# process local invariant in PlusCal

Tags: tla+, pluscal

```
process(Server \in Servers)
variable x;
{
    ...
}
```

I want to have an invariant of x > 0 for all processes. Is there any way other than making x global?

I tried

```
define {
  Inv == \A s \in Servers: x[s] > 0
}
```

But in translated TLA+ code, Inv is defined before variable x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the invariant after the `\* END TRANSLATION` line and it won't get clobbered by the PlusCal translator.